# Mac virtualize Windows

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, hardware-virtualization

I want to develop graphics application with latest OpenGL support.

Sadly, my iMac with Mac installed only supports OpenGL 4.1, with Windows in Bootcamp I go up to the latest 4.4 version.

However, I was wondering if I could get things a bit easier and install Windows in a VM instead of choosing it at boot time.

For sure, I am fully aware of VirtualBox, Parallels Desktop, VMWare and QEMU, but all of them seem to offer only a software GPU which redirects to the real GPU and can only go up to OpenGL 2.X. And for sure could never go over the OpenGL version of the host...

Do you know or do you have any experience with hardware virtualization on the Mac (Especially for GPUs)? I think Xen promises such things but seems to be outdated and not available on the Mac. Are there any alternatives which can offer OpenGL 4.4?
I would prefer having MacOS as the supervisor and don't install a Linux for this reason as booted OS.

PS: You can also tell me if it is going to be just impossible. The iMac doesn't use a desktop graphics card but a mobile GTX 680M card which probably has no VGA pass through at all, but I wasn't able to find any information on it on the internet. So I just hope that somebody in the community has tried similar things and has some experiences to share.

Answer (score 0):

Virturalization w/ GPUs is supported but not for Mac OSX. Apple TOS only allows you to run OSX ontop of apple labeled products, so even if you did have a vm server w/ a big fancy GPU, osx cannot run on that hardware.

Final Answer: Impossible

Comment: I have a iMac so I have Mac hardware. I want to do it the other way round. My Mac OS is the host with only OpenGL 4.1 support and virtualize a Windows in it with hopefully OpenGL 4.4 support if it could fully take over the GPU and would see it as its hardware. The Mac should then just grep the framebuffer and redirect it to the screen.